# Getting results from a DB based on Select options

Tags: php, html, mysql

I have a php generated select list. I'm trying to get results from my DB based on the user selected option. The list itself worked fine until I encountered an undefined index error at which point I fixed it with `isset()`. Now the value reverts to the last added value in the table. Also, and this is the main issue I'm having, the results from my query are always the last value added to the table.

If I could dig down to the bedrock of my question it would be: How do I set up a query to retrieve the results from my table based on the selected option? I.e.

```
SELECT course_name,course_duration,course_id FROM WHERE course_name='$_POST['courses']'
```

PHP File:

```
<?php
include 'mysqlconnect.php';

if ($db_found) {
    $sql = "SELECT course_id,course_name,course_duration FROM course";
    $result = mysql_query($sql);
}
?>
<p>
    <label>Select Course:</label>
    <select name="courses" id="courses">

    <?php
        //generate options in select list 
        while ($field=mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {

        //get values for later use.
        $course_name=$field['course_name'];
        $course_ID=$field['course_id'];
        $course_duration=$field['course_duration'];

        echo "<option value='".$course_name."'"; 
        if($course_name==isset($_POST['courses'])) {echo ' SELECTED';}
          echo '>' .$course_name.'</option>';
        }

    ?>
    </select>
</p>
```

Comment: ***Warning:*** Your code is ***highly vulnerable*** to ***SQL injection attacks***.  You might want to read up on that and fix it.  This seems like a good place to start: http://php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php

Answer (score 0):

At first:

```
isset()
```

just returns 'true' or 'false' if the variable you pass is set or not. So try out:

```
if($course_name == $_POST['courses']) ...
```

EDIT: Also you should make a

```
<form>
```

to submit the form when the user changed the value of the select-list. When submitting, the value of the select-list gets submitted to your script. Then try the SQL statement:

```
SELECT course_name,course_duration,course_id FROM course WHERE course_name='$_POST['courses']'
```